# Creating azure storage with powershell

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am new to Azure. I want to create a powershell script which can create a blob storage in azure and add a container. I have been through so many articles but none of them are much helpful. Can anyone help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-AzLocation | select Location
$location = "eastus"
$resourceGroup = "myResourceGroup"
New-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup -Location $location
$storageAccount = New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
  -Name "mystorageaccount" `
  -SkuName Standard_LRS `
  -Location $location `

$ctx = $storageAccount.Context
$containerName = "quickstartblobs"
new-AzStoragecontainer -Name $containerName -Context $ctx -Permission blob
```

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell#create-a-storage-account

Comment: How could I make the same using an ARM template. There's also a parameter file in that, what's that use for. Could you please help?

Comment: to pass in parameters ;) you can define parameters and use parameters file (or pass in parameters directly with powershell) to supply values for those. template sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-storage-account-create

Comment: So the reference of parameter file should be given in arm template. I'm confused here as to how can we do that?

Comment: i suggest you accept this answer and start a new one about arm templates, because these questions are not related at all